# Getting strange 'undefined method ' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Getting "undefined method `each' for #< Mark:0x00000001e057d0>"

Here is the view:

```
<% @current_marks.each do |m| %>
  <tr>
    <td class='col-md-3'><%= m.subject %></td>
    <td class='col-md-3'><%= m.professor %></td>
    <td class='col-md-3'><%= m.semester %></td>
    <td class='col-md-3'><%= m.points %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

And a controller:

```
def show
  @student = Student.find(params[:id])
  @students = Student.all
  @current_marks = Mark.find_by! student_id: @student.id
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  redirect_to :action => 'set_marks'
end
```

I've checked an Id param already and it is correct. Also I have `Mark` records in DB with correct `student_id`. How should I call `@current_marks` without any errors?

Comment: What returns `Mark.find_by! student_id: @student.id`?

Comment: @sschmeck it returns the first record with matched student_id. My fault.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`find_by` will give you the first matched record not a collection so you can not call each on that.Instead you can use where if you need all matched record

```
 @current_marks = Mark.where student_id: @student.id
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to `punitcse`'s answer, you'll also want to check your associations because invoking two class calls like you have is pretty inefficient.

--

You should be able to get away with:

```
def show
  @student = Student.find params[:id]
  @current_marks = @student.marks
end
```

This is considering the following to be set up in your models:

```
#app/models/student.rb
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :marks
end 

#app/models/mark.rb
class Mark < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :student
end
```